# How can I wire several receptacles between three-way switches so they're half switched?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have 12/2 power into first switch, 12/3 through all three split receptacles and to the second switch. I just can't wrap my head around the right connections.

Comment: What's your definition of "split receptacles"?

Comment: That's not enough wires if you want half of each outlet to be on full-time. You'd need that many just to have the outlets fully switched.

Comment: Split meaning 1 at each receptacle being hot all the time and the other being switched by the 3 ways.

Comment: You can do it in a safe manner with balanced current in every cable, using two parallel 12/3 cables, but not within code because you can't provide a proper neutral at the far switch.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri -- only one switch in a 3-way complex *needs* neutral

Comment: Is replacing the wiring an option here?

Comment: How feasible would it be to add another 12/3 between the two switches?  It need not follow the same route through the outlet boxes (though it can, if that's the most convenient way to do it).  If you're able to add that one additional wire, then none of the other wiring will need to be replaced.

Comment: @NateS.  The OP was pretty adamant about only using what was there.  Some of the comments have been deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Since OP has indicated that wiring is accessible via an attic crawl space, here is a solution that requires adding another run of 12/3 between the two switch boxes. The currents in each cable are balanced, no box has more than three wire nuts, and neutral is available at one of the switches.

[image: had to redo this one seven times to get it right]

Add a 12/3 run from one switch box to the other. This doesn't need to go anywhere near the outlet boxes, and certainly should not add to the outlet box fills by passing through them.

Feed the constant-hot to the far switch via the new cable. In the diagram I used the red wire so that each switch would have three different colors on its terminals. This should be marked with black paint or tape to indicate it is now constant-hot.

Use the other two wires as travelers back to the near switch. These should be marked with yellow paint or tape to indicate they are now travelers. This completes a standard three-way switch loop which is completely independent from the outlet runs.

Now in the near switch box you have neutral, constant-hot, and switched-hot. Distribute these to the outlets via the 12/3 segments in the usual fashion.

The switch loop current is confined to the long 12/3 and is balanced, and the outlets current is confined to the distribution 12/3 segments and is balanced.

Do NOT use the existing last 12/3 segment to provide a neutral connection at the far switch box. Remove that segment (don't just cap it off, rip it out) so that no future maintainer will attempt to use it and accidentally create an unbalanced circuit.

Comment: The OP was pretty adamant about only using what was there. Some of the comments have been deleted. That's what started "The Rant'.

Comment: OP said in a comment that he needed to use only the materials supplied by the homeowner, not that he needed to leave existing wiring in place. OP said in a comment that the wiring was accessible via the attic. - Comments are gone, I think the rant scared him.

Comment: What, is OP trying to pass a Hillbilly Electrical Code version of FizzBuzz? It can be done but only by dangerously bootlegging neutral.

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica: I don't understand this comment. - What "can be done"? What is bootlegged onto neutral?

Comment: What I mean is, if one followed the Hillbilly Electrical Code (bootlegged neutral), that frees up a wire. Using a California 3-way frees up one more, so that would suffice. The fact that the customer *knows* this is disturbing, and makes me think we're dealing with either a catty but unethical customer, *or* an investigative reporter trying to catch OP doing something wrong....... and this is a trick/test (FizzBuzz being a common test for programmers).

Answer (score 3):

### You're not wrapping your head around it *because it isn't possible*.

For the *conventional* wiring to work, there'd need to be 5 wires between the receps - 2 travelers, always-hot, neutral and switched-hot. They don't make /5 cable, so the only way to do that is conduit.

You cannot rescue the situation by throwing an additional /2 cable alongside the /3 for a couple reasons: first the 5 need to be in the same cable, and second you can't put *that many* splices in a typical box.

(It is possible to do with /4 cable using a technique called a "California 3-way", which is legal and works with 1 traveler... but will be quite a surprise to the next person.)

### Smart switches save the day again.

You put a smart-switch master at either switch location.  A smart-switch remote at the other.  The remote must communicate with the master either wireless or with powerline signaling, since there will be no datacomm cables available.  We get lucky and the wire function gets to correspond to wire color.

- White: Neutral
- Black: always-hot
- Red: switched-hot

Hook them up according to each point's needs.  The remote smart-switch will not use red.

Answer (score 2):

With the supplies given to you by the homeowner, it can't be done. Here's a simple diagram of what's needed as far as connections are concerned:
[image]

You're looking at 12/4 which exists and 12/5 NM cable which doesn't. Code doesn't allow parallel cables to be run. If you were able to install conduit from switches to receptacles and receptacles to receptacles, then you could pull the needed wires. Hope this helps explain things.

Comment: It's possible to do this with 4C+E. But you need to move to a different type of 3-way wiring. In on 1, out on 2, tie the commons together.

Comment: Yeah you can get 4/12 NM-B cable  and if you use a "California 3-way" that would work. the cable comes with two neutrals one of which would need to be sleeved or painted a live color in this application.

Comment: @Jasen  Didn't want to draw out all the possibilities.... it's Friday and Happy Hour's started...

Comment: @JACK -- 12/4 is a thing, although you're right 12/5 isn't.  (You can also use THHN in ENT for this.)

Comment: @JACK you have your ENT and your EMT mixed up :)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel        LOL  Was watch Lord of the Rings and the ENTS (trees)  fighting the ORCS...  and drinking rum and cokes.....  gotta turn this site off for the evening..lol Thanks for tip on 12/4.

Comment: Parallel cables are fine, so long as all electricity that leaves through one wire on a cable returns on a different wire in the same cable.

Comment: @Jasen, usually cable with two neutrals will be sold as 12/2/2, and cables with only one (the rest of the wires are hot colors) will be sold as 12/4, so if you buy carefully you can often avoid the need to remark colors.  YMMV, of course.

Comment: Yeah that would make sense, use a California 3-way with traveler being blue in /4 or white-red in /2/2... But that is not what OP has.

Answer (score 1):

I actually started to write the "smart switch is the solution" myself earlier, but @Harper beat me to it - and well done as usual. Based on additional information from [comments](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/202128/how-can-i-wire-several-receptacles-between-three-way-switches-so-theyre-half-sw/202139?noredirect=1#comment365639_202135):

#### Watch Out for Inspectors! And Lawyers!

**Seriously.** The norm for DIY is *a homeowner doing work in their own home*. That excludes rentals (landlord or tenant) and excludes handyman (or anyone other than a licensed electrician) doing electrical work for someone else.

In many (not all) jurisdictions, a homeowner can make certain changes (varies by jurisdiction how much - from only simple switch & receptacle replacement on up to anything short of a main panel replacement) themselves, either with no or minimal permitting requirements. However, in **most** places, someone other than the homeowner is not legally allowed to make such changes without (a) being a licensed electrician and (b) permits. I am not going to argue the pros & cons of permits. That gets rather *political*. But I will tell you that if I, as a homeowner, am relying on someone else to do the work then I expect that they know *exactly* what to do and won't (of all things) be asking a bunch of strangers on the internet what to do. Not when it comes to health & safety. Conversely, if I, as a homeowner, buy stuff and say to the professional "use this, save a few dollars for me", and the professional does not think this is the right solution then I expect that professional to tell me "no, can't do it" or "you can use that but you are better off with something else", etc.

This particular question about switches & receptacles may not be a big one, but if the professional doesn't know how to wire it up (or indeed that it **can't** be wired up with the supplied equipment) then I'd seriously worry about workmanship and other things like proper connection of grounds, GFCI where required, etc.

I have done some limited electrical work myself (I am not an electrician) but *never* on someone else's house. I have hired electricians to do the stuff I can't - and looking back, I can see they **really** knew what they were doing, to the extent that I am still learning stuff now, many years later, that I can see they did for me *properly, without checking with me, just doing what needed to be done*. They know I'm not made of money, but when it came to safety they knew not to cut corners.

Rant over.

Comment: It's a rant. Relevant but long and annoying and may well get deleted. But based on the comment to @Harper's answer, it seems pretty clear this is someone hired by homeowner and based on the question it is pretty clear that OP is not anything *close* to a licensed electrician.

Comment: Strongly agree with @manassehkatz -- it's a frame challenge, not an answer, but it had to be said.

Comment: I didn't realize that it was a response to a comment _on that answer_. You should link to it (grab the URL from the date stamp) or quote it in your answer for posterity.

Comment: I love a good rant.

Comment: I must have missed quite a tempest. The comments seem to be deleted and 2 downvotes.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Friday night smackdown.... and upvoted ya..

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I should have quoted the whole comment instead of making a link. Basically, OP admitted to doing (or trying...) work for a homeowner using homeowner supplied cable + "can't possibly do smart switches because homeowner won't go for it" type of remarks. Which meant *not* true DIY + "for hire but not a real pro" -> hence, my response.